# Trying to store encrypted AES data into mySQL database using Java

Tags: java, mysql, encryption

I'm trying to store a byte array into mySQL which contains encrypted 'password'. I've tried both using both Blob and varbinary datatype, but when I extract the encrypted data, it doesn't seem to decrypted correctly as the stored byte array is not the same as the one I started with.

The code below for the encrypt/decryption

```
   public byte[] encrypt(String password){
    byte[] encrypted = null;
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encrypted;
}

public String decrypt(byte[] encrypted){
    String decrypted = null;
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decrypted;
}
```

I've printed out the byte array to see if there was the difference, as you can see during the transition into the database it does change and I'm not sure how to overcome this problem

Output of byte array (Top is original byte array, bottom is from the database)

```
84-48-4282-15-60-21-38-41944477106182
916664495599545657505332
```

Just to clarify, if I try to decrypt using database byte array I recieve this error:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decryption with padded cipher
```

Also as mentioned in the comments section, I've tried converted it into a string and and storing it in DB then decrypt it but I get the same error.

I've even tried using Hashing with SHA-256 and it's the same thing the byte array that I'm retrieving is completely different to what it was originally

variables I'm using

```
byte[] pa = p.hashPass("Hello World");
byte[] dbp = null;
```

This is the statement I'm using to store/get the data

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("INSERT INTO staffaccounts(`ID`, `UserName`, `Password`, `Salt`) VALUES (NULL, 'admin', '"+pa+"', '')");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM staffaccounts");
rs.next();
dbp = rs.getBytes("password");
```

Comment: Is DB datatype for the column where this value is being stored `VARCHAR`?

Comment: No atm I'm using varbinary, I've tried blob too but same issue

Comment: You can try using `VARCHAR`. Store the value in DB as String and then parse it accordingly after Reading it from DB. Does it make sense?

Comment: I've tried that, even parsing the bytes/string in ISO-8859-1 format, alas it did not work

Comment: You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: This is just a little project, and in no way going to be used. Thank you for your concern though.

Comment: @ArtjomB. As no one knows the answer, I've even tried to implement it using SHA-256, what I'm getting from the table isn't the same byte array as what I have originally inputted

Comment: Use the database's encryption functions. Don't write code when you don't need to. 'No-one knows the answer' is not a valid logical inference from 'no-one has posted an answer'. You haven't shown how this was put into the database, or retrieved.

Comment: @user2004685 No, it doesn't make sense. Cipher text is binary, not character data.

Comment: I think he meant to convert it to a String and store it as a varchar. It is possible to do, however I get the same error as specified above

Comment: If that's what he meant he should have said so. I am commenting on what he actually wrote. I don't consider speculation about it to be at all profitable. You still haven't provided your database code, and without it your question is not answerable.

Comment: I've provided the statement code, I'm using to insert into the database and how I am retrieving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are inserting the value returned by `byte[].toString()`, which is *not* the content of the byte array.

You should be doing this via positional parameters in a `PreparedStatement.` *Never* concatenate values into an SQL statement.