# String encrypted by Java AES, Decrypt in Python Issue

Tags: java, python, aes, cx-oracle, pycrypto

I have a Java code to encrypt(AES encryption with key) a JSON and store it in Oracle database LONG RAW column.

I have a python code to read the data from that column and decrypt. Below is the code i am using for decryption.

The code is running fine but i am not able to see the JSON after decryption instead some unreadable string is getting printed.

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(u'select KEY_VALUE from TEST1')
encoded = "";

for row in c:
    encoded = base64.b64encode(row[0])

print(encoded)
key = 'F50D518354690A8630BCE683B7AC8F55'

aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, 16 * b'\0')

print(aes.decrypt(encoded))

conn.close()
```

Can you please point where am i wrong.

Also the Encoded String is getting printed fine and matches the value in Oracle database.

**I tried using AES.MODE_ECB since the java code was not iv to encrypt but still the same issue**

Below is the Encryption and Decryption Code in java. I want to replicate the decrypt in python.

**decrypt**

```
public static  String decryptText(byte[] byteCipherText, SecretKey secKey) throws Exception {

                // AES defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java 7

                System.out.println(secKey.toString());

                Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

                aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey);

                byte[] bytePlainText = aesCipher.doFinal(byteCipherText);

                return new String(bytePlainText);

            }
```

**encrypt**

```
public static byte[] encryptText(String plainText, String key) throws Exception {

                    // AES defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java 7

                    System.out.println("key is "+key);
                    SecretKey secKey=decodeKeyFromString(key);

                    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

                    aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);

                    byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());

                    return byteCipherText;

                }
```

The decodeKeyFromString method has just the below line :

```
 SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
```

I Even tried writing the encrypted value as blob in oracle and then doing decryption but still the same garbage values.

```
for row in c:
            encoded=row[0]

        encrypted= open(blobpath,'wb')

        encrypted.write(encoded.read())

        encrypted.close()

        with open('encrypted.txt', 'r') as myfile:
            data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

        key='F50D518354690A8630BCE683B7AC8F55'

        aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)

        e=unpad(aes.decrypt(base64.b64encode(data)))
```

Comment: please add the java encryption code , the cipher and the original message

Comment: add this function please decodeKeyFromString

Comment: Why are you base64-encoding your ciphertext? Remember: encode after encryption, decode before decryption.

Comment: how you store the encrypted data? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089759/trying-to-store-encrypted-aes-data-into-mysql-database-using-java